# Codename One TextArea Padding has no effect

Tags: codenameone

Both the TextField and the TextArea in the attached image have the same UIID. I have set the left padding be 1 mm using theme designer.

You can see that the left padding is applied to the TextField but not the TextArea.

I have also attempted to set it manually in the code using gui_TextArea.getAllStyles().setPaddingLeft(1); and gui_textArea.getAllStyles().setPadding(1,1,1,1); to no effect.

There does not appear to be a setTextUIID() method for TextArea.

How do we set the padding for this component?

[image: The left padding is applied to the TextField but not the TextArea.]

Full source per Steve's request:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.this.that.gui;

import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.TextField;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.Style;
import com.this.that.Constants;
import com.this.that.Main;
import com.this.that.util.MyNetwork;
import com.this.that.util.MyToolbar;
import com.this.that.util.MyValidator;
import com.this.that.util.User;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * GUI builder created Form
 */
public class Contact extends com.codename1.ui.Form {

    private User user;

    public Contact() {
        this(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.getGlobalResources());
    }

    public Contact(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
        initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
        Style s = gui_Message.getAllStyles();
        s.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
        s.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        this.revalidate();
    }

//-- DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!!!
    private com.codename1.ui.Container gui_welcomeContainer = new com.codename1.ui.Container(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout());
    private com.codename1.ui.Label gui_null = new com.codename1.ui.Label();
    private com.codename1.ui.Container gui_BodyContainer = new com.codename1.ui.Container(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout(com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    private com.codename1.ui.Label gui_spacer1 = new com.codename1.ui.Label();
    private com.codename1.ui.TextField gui_Subject = new com.codename1.ui.TextField();
    private com.codename1.ui.TextArea gui_Message = new com.codename1.ui.TextArea();
    private com.codename1.ui.Button gui_SubmitButton = new com.codename1.ui.Button();


// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void guiBuilderBindComponentListeners() {
        EventCallbackClass callback = new EventCallbackClass();
        gui_SubmitButton.addActionListener(callback);
    }

    class EventCallbackClass implements com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener, com.codename1.ui.events.DataChangedListener {
        private com.codename1.ui.Component cmp;
        public EventCallbackClass(com.codename1.ui.Component cmp) {
            this.cmp = cmp;
        }

        public EventCallbackClass() {
        }

        public void actionPerformed(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
            com.codename1.ui.Component sourceComponent = ev.getComponent();

            if(sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() != null && (sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() instanceof com.codename1.components.MultiButton || sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() instanceof com.codename1.components.SpanButton)) {
                sourceComponent = sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent();
            }

            if(sourceComponent == gui_SubmitButton) {
                onSubmitButtonActionEvent(ev);
            }
        }

        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
        }
    }
    private void initGuiBuilderComponents(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
        guiBuilderBindComponentListeners();
        setLayout(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout(com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        setScrollableY(false);
                setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        setTitle("");
        setName("Contact");
        addComponent(gui_welcomeContainer);
        gui_welcomeContainer.setUIID("welcomeContainer");
                gui_welcomeContainer.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_welcomeContainer.setName("welcomeContainer");
        ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout)gui_welcomeContainer.getLayout()).setCenterBehavior(com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER);
        gui_welcomeContainer.addComponent(com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout.CENTER, gui_null);
        gui_null.setText("Contact Us");
        gui_null.setUIID("welcomeLabel");
                gui_null.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        addComponent(gui_BodyContainer);
                gui_BodyContainer.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_BodyContainer.setName("BodyContainer");
        gui_BodyContainer.addComponent(gui_spacer1);
        gui_BodyContainer.addComponent(gui_Subject);
        gui_BodyContainer.addComponent(gui_Message);
        gui_BodyContainer.addComponent(gui_SubmitButton);
        gui_spacer1.setText(" ");
                gui_spacer1.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_spacer1.setName("spacer1");
        gui_Subject.setScrollVisible(true);
        gui_Subject.setHint("  Subject");
        gui_Subject.setUIID("TextField");
                gui_Subject.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_Subject.setName("Subject");
        gui_Subject.setColumns(20);
        gui_Message.setHint("  Please enter a brief message");
        gui_Message.setUIID("TextField");
                gui_Message.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_Message.setName("Message");
        gui_Message.setMaxSize(1000);
        gui_Message.setColumns(20);
        gui_Message.setRows(10);
        gui_SubmitButton.setText("Submit");
                gui_SubmitButton.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_SubmitButton.setName("SubmitButton");
        gui_SubmitButton.setTextPosition(com.codename1.ui.Component.BOTTOM);
        gui_welcomeContainer.setUIID("welcomeContainer");
                gui_welcomeContainer.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_welcomeContainer.setName("welcomeContainer");
        ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout)gui_welcomeContainer.getLayout()).setCenterBehavior(com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER);
                gui_BodyContainer.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_BodyContainer.setName("BodyContainer");
    }// </editor-fold>

//-- DON'T EDIT ABOVE THIS LINE!!!
        public void onSubmitButtonActionEvent(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
        if (gui_Subject.getText().equals("") || gui_Message.getText().equals("")) {
            Main.showDialog("You must enter all fields.");
        } else {
            if (user.getName() == null || user.getEmail() == null) {
                requestNameOrEmail();
            }
            else{
                sendMessage(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void requestNameOrEmail(){
        Dialog d = new Dialog(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        d.setTitle("Require Name/Email to Send");

        Container nameLayeredLayout = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
        TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setHint("Name");
        nameLayeredLayout.add(name);

        Container emailLayeredLayout = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
        TextField email = new TextField();
        email.setHint("Email");
        emailLayeredLayout.add(email);

        if(user.getName() != null){
            name.setText(user.getName());
        }
        if(user.getEmail() != null){
            email.setText(user.getEmail());
        }

        Map<String, Boolean> validatorParams = new HashMap<>();
        validatorParams.put("name", false);
        validatorParams.put("email", false);
        MyValidator v = new MyValidator(validatorParams);
        v.setupLengthConstraint(nameLayeredLayout, name, 2, 30, "name", "Name must be 2-30 characters.");
        v.setupEmailConstraint(emailLayeredLayout, email, "email", "Email not valid.");

        Container buttonCnt = new Container();
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener((l) -> {
            d.dispose();
        });

        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener((l) -> {
            if (v.isValid()) {
                d.dispose();
                sendMessage(true);
            }

        });
        buttonCnt.add(cancel).add(submit);

        d.add(nameLayeredLayout).add(emailLayeredLayout).add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(buttonCnt));
        d.show();
    }

    private void sendMessage(boolean updateUser) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("update_user",String.valueOf(updateUser));
        params.put("sender_name", user.getName());
        params.put("sender_email", user.getEmail());
        params.put("sender_udid", Display.getInstance().getUdid());
        params.put("subject", gui_Subject.getText());
        params.put("message", gui_Message.getText());
        MyNetwork.getInstance().getNetworkObject("POST", Constants.SEND_EMAIL, params, "noDialog");
        Main.showDialog("Message sent.");
        Home form = new Home();
        MyToolbar.getInstance().setupToolbar(form);
        form.show();
    }

}
```

Here is the .gui for the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<component type="Form" layout="BoxLayout" boxLayoutAxis="Y"  scrollableY="false" title="" name="Contact">
    <component type="Container" layout="BorderLayout" borderLayoutAbsoluteCenter="true"  uiid="welcomeContainer" name="welcomeContainer">
        <component type="Label" uiid="welcomeLabel" text="Contact Us">
            <layoutConstraint value="Center" />
        </component>
    </component>
    <component type="Container" layout="BoxLayout" boxLayoutAxis="Y"  name="BodyContainer">
        <component type="Label" text=" " name="spacer1">
        </component>
        <component type="TextField" uiid="TextField" hint="  Subject" scrollVisible="true" columns="20" constraint="0" name="Subject">
        </component>
        <component type="TextArea" uiid="TextField" hint="  Please enter a brief message" rows="10" columns="20" maxSize="1000" constraint="0" name="Message">
        </component>
        <component type="Button" text="Submit" textPosition="2" name="SubmitButton" actionEvent="true">
        </component>
    </component>
</component>
```

Here are the relevant lines from theme.xml (uiid is set to TextField)

```
    <gradient key="TextArea.bgGradient" color1="0" color2="0" posX="0.5" posY="0.5" radius="1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.bgType" value="0" />
    <border key="TextArea.border" type="image" i1="TextField.borderTop_1.png" i2="TextField.borderBottom_1.png" i3="TextField.borderLeft_1.png" i4="TextField.borderRight_1.png" i5="TextField.borderTopL_1.png" i6="TextField.borderTopR_1.png" i7="TextField.borderBottomL_1.png" i8="TextField.borderBottomR_1.png" i9="TextField.borderCenter_1.png" />
    <val key="TextArea.fgColor" value="0" />
    <font key="TextArea.font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainRegular" family="native:MainRegular" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.marUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextArea.margin" value="1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.padUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextArea.padding" value="0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0" />
    <gradient key="TextArea.press#bgGradient" color1="0" color2="0" posX="0.5" posY="0.5" radius="1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#bgType" value="0" />
    <border key="TextArea.press#border" type="image" i1="TextField.borderTop_1.png" i2="TextField.borderBottom_1.png" i3="TextField.borderLeft_1.png" i4="TextField.borderRight_1.png" i5="TextField.borderTopL_1.png" i6="TextField.borderTopR_1.png" i7="TextField.borderBottomL_1.png" i8="TextField.borderBottomR_1.png" i9="TextField.borderCenter_1.png" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#fgColor" value="0" />
    <font key="TextArea.press#font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainRegular" family="native:MainRegular" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#marUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#margin" value="1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#padUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#padding" value="0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.press#transparency" value="0" />
    <gradient key="TextArea.sel#bgGradient" color1="0" color2="0" posX="0.5" posY="0.5" radius="1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#bgType" value="0" />
    <border key="TextArea.sel#border" type="image" i1="TextField.borderTop_1.png" i2="TextField.borderBottom_1.png" i3="TextField.borderLeft_1.png" i4="TextField.borderRight_1.png" i5="TextField.borderTopL_1.png" i6="TextField.borderTopR_1.png" i7="TextField.borderBottomL_1.png" i8="TextField.borderBottomR_1.png" i9="TextField.borderCenter_1.png" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#fgColor" value="0" />
    <font key="TextArea.sel#font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainRegular" family="native:MainRegular" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#marUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#margin" value="1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#padUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#padding" value="0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextArea.sel#transparency" value="0" />
    <val key="TextArea.transparency" value="0" />
    <gradient key="TextField.bgGradient" color1="0" color2="0" posX="0.5" posY="0.5" radius="1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.bgType" value="0" />
    <border key="TextField.border" type="image" i1="TextField.borderTop_1.png" i2="TextField.borderBottom_1.png" i3="TextField.borderLeft_1.png" i4="TextField.borderRight_1.png" i5="TextField.borderTopL_1.png" i6="TextField.borderTopR_1.png" i7="TextField.borderBottomL_1.png" i8="TextField.borderBottomR_1.png" i9="TextField.borderCenter_1.png" />
    <val key="TextField.fgColor" value="0" />
    <font key="TextField.font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainRegular" family="native:MainRegular" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.0" />
    <val key="TextField.marUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextField.margin" value="1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.padUnit" value="0,2,0,2" />
    <val key="TextField.padding" value="0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0" />
    <gradient key="TextField.press#bgGradient" color1="0" color2="0" posX="0.5" posY="0.5" radius="1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.press#bgType" value="0" />
    <border key="TextField.press#border" type="image" i1="TextField.borderTop_1.png" i2="TextField.borderBottom_1.png" i3="TextField.borderLeft_1.png" i4="TextField.borderRight_1.png" i5="TextField.borderTopL_1.png" i6="TextField.borderTopR_1.png" i7="TextField.borderBottomL_1.png" i8="TextField.borderBottomR_1.png" i9="TextField.borderCenter_1.png" />
    <val key="TextField.press#fgColor" value="0" />
    <font key="TextField.press#font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainRegular" family="native:MainRegular" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.0" />
    <val key="TextField.press#marUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextField.press#margin" value="1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.press#padUnit" value="0,2,0,2" />
    <val key="TextField.press#padding" value="0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.press#transparency" value="0" />
    <gradient key="TextField.sel#bgGradient" color1="0" color2="0" posX="0.5" posY="0.5" radius="1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#bgType" value="0" />
    <border key="TextField.sel#border" type="image" i1="TextField.borderTop_1.png" i2="TextField.borderBottom_1.png" i3="TextField.borderLeft_1.png" i4="TextField.borderRight_1.png" i5="TextField.borderTopL_1.png" i6="TextField.borderTopR_1.png" i7="TextField.borderBottomL_1.png" i8="TextField.borderBottomR_1.png" i9="TextField.borderCenter_1.png" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#fgColor" value="0" />
    <font key="TextField.sel#font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainRegular" family="native:MainRegular" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.0" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#marUnit" value="2,2,2,2" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#margin" value="1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#padUnit" value="0,2,0,2" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#padding" value="0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#transparency" value="0" />
    <val key="TextField.transparency" value="0" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the Theme Designer showing padding for Selected TextField UIID. Padding in millimeters is also applied to unselected and pressed. Both components share this UIID but the padding is only appearing on the text field component, not the text area component. This behavior does not change if the lines that I added in the code to set padding are present or not.

[image]

You see in the screenshot that left and right are both in mm while top/bottom are in pixels. I also set it so that all four units are mm and it did not change the behavior.

(We are using CN1 v4.0)

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this issue with what you've posted here.  Something must be overriding the padding of that textarea after this point.  Can you post the full source for the class?

Comment: @stevehannah, I modified the question to include full source.

Comment: @stevehannah, please note that the only reason I included setPadding in the class was because the padding was not being applied when it was set in the Theme Designer. Ideally, the padding as set in the Theme Designer should work, but it does not appear to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I ended up doing the following:

1. Reverted my project to a prior commit that did not have any padding styling for TextArea or TextField
2. In the Theme Designer I edited the padding on each state one-by-one instead of copying the styling from one state to another.

I am suspecting but cannot say for certain that the issue was caused by the act of copy/pasting the styling in the Theme Designer. AFAIK that is the only difference between the working and non-working versions of the styling. I seem to recall running into issues when doing copy/paste in the designer in the past.

Answer (score 0):

`setPaddingLeft(1);` would override `setPadding(1,1,1,1);` and visa versa. You need to make sure that you do these things before the form is shown and if you do them after you need to revalidate as this will impact layout.

However, in your case I'm guessing you need to invoke `setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);` to make sure that padding is in a visible unit. Make sure to invoke that **before** the `setPadding` call.

```
Form hi = new Form("Padding", BoxLayout.y());

TextArea unpadded = new TextArea("Unpadded");
TextArea padded = new TextArea("Padded");
Style s = padded.getAllStyles();
s.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
s.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
hi.addAll(unpadded, padded);

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Adding setPaddingUnit() and revalidate() do not appear to make a difference. I have added a code snippet to the question.

Is there a reason why setting padding in the theme designer does not work either?

Comment: So, from your edited answer, it would appear that you are indicating that in order to have padding on TextArea we must create the Form programmatically?

Our application is built using GUI builder and the theme designer. Why does padding not work with GUI Builder and Theme Designer?

I also used Style s = padded.getAllStyles(); etc as in your example in place of the code in my example, followed by revalidate. Which did not work. Why does it not work after the form has been shown and revalidated?

Comment: No. It would work exactly the same with the GUI builder unless you've set styling in the GUI builder to contradict the code.

Comment: Please take a look at the full-source that I added at Steve's request. If I remove lines 40-43 so that ONLY the GUI builder styling exists, the padding is not applied.  (I added lines 40-43 in an attempt to force padding because the GUI builder styling was not working) I have attached every line from the GUI builder .xml file that applies to these elements. As you can see from my source code above, nowhere else is the styling for TextField or TextArea modified.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. When you style with the manual method it doesn't work or when you style via the GUI builder it doesn't work? I don't see any GUI builder styling in the code you published, only the manual and designer styling.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the Theme Designer styling, not GUI builder styling. I got the terms mixed. I originally created the form in "new" gui builder (cn1 v 3.8) I attempted to apply styling in the theme designer to add padding to TextArea and TextField. The padding did not work for the TextArea so I attempted to add it in the code and was unsuccessful there as well. I then upgraded to cn1 v4 in case there was a bug in 3.8 but it still didn't work. I changed the uiid to "TextField" so I could show it worked on one component type but not the other. No padding via Theme Designer or code.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. You've set the UIID of the `TextArea` to `TextField` in the GUI builder UI.

Comment: No. That was intentional. As I stated earlier, I set the UIID of the Text Area component to `TextField` so that I could show both components had the same UIID but only the text field component had padding applied. If both components have the same UIID then they both should have padding. However, the padding is only showing up for the Text Field component. There is no padding on the Text Area component even though it has the same UIID.

Comment: I should probably re-state that padding was also added to BOTH the TextArea and theTextField UIIDs in the theme designer.

Comment: You only applied the padding in the unselected mode of the text field. It also looks like you padded in pixels which might be almost invisible.

Comment: In the theme designer, the padding was applied to Unselected, Selected, and Pressed. It was applied in millimeters. I will attach a screenshot to the original question. Aside from that though. The fact remains that BOTH the text field and the text area components are sharing the same UIID and the padding is appearing on text field component but NOT on the text area component.

Comment: OK I missed some of that in the XML, it's a bit too long. But I still don't see much padding...  `<val key="TextField.sel#padUnit" value="0,2,0,2" />
    <val key="TextField.sel#padding" value="0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0" />`. You will need more padding on a multiline than on a single line as the text layout algorithm is different.